# UIView on the center of UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uitableview

How can I put my UIView (`loadingView`), which was loading from UITableViewController on the center of screen, regardless of the position of the scroll?

Comment: Dont use a UITableViewController, that's how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add the view to the superview of the tableview, like this:

```
loadingView.center = self.tableView.center;
[self.tableView.superview addSubview:loadingView];
```

and remove it (removeFromSuperview) when you are done with it.
It will appear on top of the table, centered to the table, but won't scroll with the table.

Answer (score 1):

Shift your code into a UIViewController subclass instead of a UITableViewController subclass.  That way, you can add your loading view to an actual view instead of a table.  Then, conform to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` in your .h, set the delegates and add the table as a subview of the main view.  You won't even miss that ol' UITableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the loadingView to the table's subView. Do this instead:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:loadingView];
```

This solves having to shift code to a UIViewController